# RegEx : How To Capture 'String' Across Multiple Lines/Paragaphs (With Possible 'Anchor' At End Of String)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

**Input** :

```
<tr>
...
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text">M-GOOG-NYC-03-SW01</td>
<td class="text"><a href="/event-reporter?child=ping4;device=limit=1000;mode=table+graph;navbar=off;refresh=60;sort=lastchange;sort_dir=f;time=last4h; return false;">8.8.8.8</a></td>
<td class="comma">2</td>
<td class="elapsed"><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Last Change: Sun, Oct 17, 2021 at 09:16">2 mins 14 secs</div></td>
<td class="text">up</td>
</tr>
<tr>
...
</tr>
```

**Objective** :

I am looking for the RegEx logic to match a HTML row, where
the last column has the word "up" or "down" in that column,
ie.

```
<td class="text">up</td>
```

or

```
<td class="text">down</td>
```

So that once I satisfy in this condition, ie. look for "Up" or "Down" in the last column,
I want to change the background colour of the first column (or even the entire row), by inserting some small HTML code into:

```
<td class="text">M-GOOG-NYC-03-SW01</td>
```

to make it this

```
<td class="text" "style=background-color:#FFCC99">M-GOOG-NYC-03-SW01</td>
```

Basically, I am thinking along the lines of the 'anchors' should be these :

Start - `\n<tr>\n<td class=\"text\"`

End - `\n<td class=\"text\">up<\/td>\n<\/tr>`

The thing is, some rows that start with `\n<tr>` , but don't have the adjacent column `<td class>` next to it.

Also, the multiple strings / paragraphs in between the anchors, contain a lot of semi-colons, quotation marks, equal signs, percentage symbols, hyphens, angle-brackets, etc.

If it's 'complex' to modify just that first column, then I would like some help to find out how to insert the HTML into the first row,
ie. `\n<tr>` becomes `<\n<tr "style=background-color:#FFCC99">`

For me, that could be a better solution, ie. highlighting an entire row,
based on upon a keyword, in the last column (ie. UP or DOWN).

( However, I would still like to know how to insert something in the first column, because that was my aim all this time, before having to come here)

**Attempt**:

I have tried to locate the 'string', to start from \n\n<td class="text">
with the end at <td\sclass="text">up</td>\n</tr>
and then, attempting to use capture groups to insert the desired HTML code into it.

Some things I tried :

```
replace((?<=\n<tr>\n<td class=\"text\")[\s\S\D\W]*(?=\n<td class=\"text\">up<\/td>\n<\/tr>))/igm,'style=\"background-color:#FFCC99;\"$1');

replace(/((?<=\n<tr>\n<td class=\"text\")[\s\S]*(?=up<\/td>\n<\/tr>))/igm,'style=\"background-color:#FFCC99;\"$1');

replace(/(\n<tr>\n<td\sclass=\"text\">)([\s\S\D\W]*)(<td\sclass=\"text\">up<\/td>\n<\/tr>)/igm,'<td class=\"text\" style=\"background-color:#CCCCCC;\">$2');
```

I just kept getting stumped, because either:

- it would match the instance once
- it would match the first row `<tr>` but skip another row `<tr>`, and end the string with a different `</tr>`

Comment: I was trying to match in Groups: 1st Group: <tr><td class="text" | 2nd Group: >(up|down)</td></tr> | My replacement would be: $1 style=xxx $2

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not recommended to manipulate HTML with regex.

The following isn't a watertight solution but it may be good enough.

```js
const html = `
<tr>
...
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text">M-GOOG-NYC-03-SW01</td>
<td class="text"><a href="/event-reporter?child=ping4;device=limit=1000;mode=table+graph;navbar=off;refresh=60;sort=lastchange;sort_dir=f;time=last4h; return false;">8.8.8.8</a></td>
<td class="comma">2</td>
<td class="elapsed"><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Last Change: Sun, Oct 17, 2021 at 09:16">2 mins 14 secs</div></td>
<td class="text">up</td>
</tr>
<tr>
...
</tr>
`;

const lastCol = /<td class="text">(up|down)<\/td>[^<>]*<\/tr>/; 
const match = html.match(lastCol);

if (match === null) {
  console.log('No match!');
} else {  
  console.log(`Direction is ${match[1]}`);
  const firstCol = /(?<=<tr>[^<>]*<td class="text")>/;
  console.log(html.replace(firstCol, ' style="background-color:#FFCC99">'));
}
```

To match the first column, a positive lookbehind is used to only match the column which has no angle brackets behind it in the string before `</tr>` appears.

`[^<>]*` means match zero or more characters that are not angle brackets.

The above only looks for one match and makes one replacement, but it is not difficult to adapt it to perform many.

Comment: Thank you for contribution. I was adding some 'simple' RegEx code, to a Userscript (in Javascript) & slowly building up all of the little manipulations that I needed to do to a HTML page.  I don't have control of the HTML page/server and it needed to be in pure Javascript, because I can't have access to any JQuery either.  It's a 3rd-party software & running on servers, that I don't control.  I only have 'view' access, and the HTML page served is bland, and I was needing to add more colour to it.

Comment: I was trying to match in Groups: 1st Group: <tr><td class="text" | 2nd Group: >(up|down)</td></tr> | So, my replacement would be: $1 style=xxx $2 (I can sort of get this to work, but it does not repeat the matches & starts on the first 'wrong' <tr>)